# Python SQL query to retrieve data from relational DB

Tags: python, mysql, relational-database, mariadb

I have the following database tables:

```
SENSORS: sensor_id, type_id, location_id, pin_id
SENSOR_TYPES:type_id, type_name, parameter
LOCATIONS: location_id, room
PI_PINS: pin_id, broadcom, wiring_pi, description
```

Relationships have been established between SENSORS and the other three tables through the x_id fields.

How can I construct python code to run an SQL query that will return a dict containing {sensor_id:type_name}? I think the following query should work but I'm not sure how to wrap this up in python to return a dict.

```
SELECT sensors.sensor_id, sensor_types.type_name
FROM sensors
INNER JOIN sensor_types
ON sensors.type_id=sensor_types.type_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, turns out there's a dict cursor for this. For posterity, here is my working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import MySQLdb

# Open databse connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="****",user="****",passwd="****",db="****")

#Prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cur = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

#Execute SQL query using execute() method
cur.execute("SELECT sensor_id, sensor_types.type_name FROM sensors INNER JOIN sensor_types ON sensors.type_id=sensor_types.type_id")

#Fetch the results
data = cur.fetchall()

#Print out results
for row in data:
    print row["sensor_id"],row["type_name"]

#Disconnect from server
db.close()
```